# How do I use timeout in transitions to exit a state and stop further execution of on_enter_state function

Tags: python, transition

I'm trying to build what I hope is a fairly simple state machine to control a program attached to an LCD display and push button. I have a callback called buttonPressedCallback to transition between states and I'd like a timeout to halt the current LCD display message after a given time if the button is not pressed. I thought I had it figured out, but it doesn't seem to respond as I expect. The button callback i haven't played with really, but just while experimenting with the timeout functionality I noticed that my code quit a lot sooner than expected. I want to use this as a much more sophisticated state machine for other projects so I need to get the basics right.

Here is my code:

```
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions.states import add_state_features, Timeout
from gpiozero import Button
import time

BUTTON_PIN = 18


@add_state_features(Timeout)
class CustomStateMachine(Machine):
    pass


class simpleMachine(object):

    states = [{'name': 'dummy', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              {'name': 'start', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              'waiting']

    def __init__(self, button):

        self.button = button

        self.machine = CustomStateMachine(model=self, states=simpleMachine.states, initial='dummy')
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger='buttonPressCallback', source='start', dest='waiting')
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger='buttonPressCallback', source='waiting', dest='start')
        self.machine.add_transition('timeoutTransition', '*', 'waiting')

        self.button.when_pressed = self.buttonPressCallback

    def on_enter_start(self):
        self.printState()
        print("doing 'things' for 15 secs, timeout should happen first")
        time.sleep(15)
        print("Start state time.sleep() ended")
        print("Spent %s seconds in start state" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def on_enter_dummy(self):
        self.printState()

    def on_enter_waiting(self):
        self.printState()
        print("Nothing happens here, just waiting")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Waiting state time.sleep() ended")

    def printState(self):
        print("Entered state {}".format(self.state))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    start_time = time.time()

    btn = Button(pin=BUTTON_PIN, bounce_time=0.1)

    testMachine = simpleMachine(btn)

    print("State Machine started")

    testMachine.to_start()

    print("Program ran for %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Here is what I expect to happen:

1. testMachine starts in "dummy" state
2. testMachine is explicitly moved into "start" state with the call to testMachine.to_start()
3. start state is doing "something" for 15 seconds but timeout fires after 5 seconds and calls the timeoutTransition
4. timeout transition moves testMachine to the waiting state
5. waiting continues indefinitely, waiting for the button press to fire the transition that would move it back to the start state

What actually happens:

> ````
> (.env) dietpi@DietPi:~/rgb_clock$ sudo -E .env/bin/python test.py
> State Machine started
> Entered state start
> doing 'things' for 15 secs, timeout should happen first
> Entered state waiting
> Nothing happens here, just waiting
> Start state time.sleep() ended
> Spent 15.149317979812622 seconds in start state
> Program ran for 15.153512001037598 seconds
> (.env) dietpi@DietPi:~/rgb_clock$ ```
> ````

I'm expecting this is something to do with asyncio and threading but I had hoped that transitions and timeout would take care of that for me.

Any thoughts on why it's not performing as expected very welcome and advise on how to actually implement the functionality I'm looking for (still using transitions as I hope to use this for a more complicated project that would be very hard to track/read with lots of if/else/while statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, everything you described is actually happening. I guess what confuses you is that your implicit step "3a" (callback `on_enter_start` is canceled and the main thread stops sleeping) isn't happening. Additionally, the the fact that timeout threads are daemon threads lead to the second problem which is that your program just exits when `on_enter_start` is done.

I modified your example a bit and use `DEBUG` logging to get all steps that are actually happening here. `transitions` uses logging quite extensively. So it's a good idea to turn on `logging` if things don't work as expected. For productive execution `INFO` is usually enough.

```py
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions.states import add_state_features, Timeout
import time
import logging


@add_state_features(Timeout)
class CustomStateMachine(Machine):
    pass


class SimpleMachine(object):

    states = [{'name': 'dummy', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              {'name': 'start', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              'waiting']

    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = CustomStateMachine(model=self, states=SimpleMachine.states, initial='dummy')
        self.machine.add_transition('timeoutTransition', '*', 'waiting')

    def on_enter_start(self):
        print("doing 'things' for 15 secs, timeout should happen first")
        time.sleep(15)
        print("Start state time.sleep() ended")
        print("Spent %s seconds in start state" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def on_enter_waiting(self):
        print("Nothing happens here, just waiting")
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
        print("Waiting state time.sleep() ended")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    start_time = time.time()
    test_machine = SimpleMachine()
    print("State Machine started")
    test_machine.to_start()
    print("Program ran for %s seconds" % (time.time() - start_time))
    assert test_machine.state == 'waiting'
```

Logging output:

```
State Machine started
doing 'things' for 15 secs, timeout should happen first
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed machine preparation callbacks before conditions.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Initiating transition from state dummy to state start...
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callbacks before conditions.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callback before transition.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Exiting state dummy. Processing callbacks...
INFO:transitions.core:Exited state dummy
DEBUG:transitions.core:Entering state start. Processing callbacks...
# This is where on_enter_start is called and will block due to time.sleep
DEBUG:transitions.extensions.states:Timeout state start. Processing callbacks...
# The next event is the timeout be triggered (in a Thread!) and timeout callbacks
# will be processed (timeoutTransition)
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed machine preparation callbacks before conditions.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Initiating transition from state start to state waiting...
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callbacks before conditions.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callback before transition.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Exiting state start. Processing callbacks...
# state start is left! 
INFO:transitions.core:Exited state start
DEBUG:transitions.core:Entering state waiting. Processing callbacks...
# state waiting is entered. Your callback on_enter_waiting will be executed in
# the Timeout thread and block there
Nothing happens here, just waiting
Start state time.sleep() ended
Spent 15.001700162887573 seconds in start state
# in your main thread your on_enter_start callback is now done
Program ran for 15.001909732818604 seconds
INFO:transitions.core:Executed callback 'on_enter_start'
INFO:transitions.core:Entered state start
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed callback after transition.
DEBUG:transitions.core:Executed machine finalize callbacks
# The program will exit since timeout threads are daemon threads.
# the reason is that waiting timeouts do not block a program's exit
Process finished with exit code 0
```

So, how to deal with this. Right now, I can think of three different attempts:

#### 1. Organize your heavy processing in threads

- make sure callbacks do not block event processing of the state machine
- run heavy processing in threads/a single working thread.
- suggestion: make your processing threads check for a flag regurlarly, so they can gracefully exit when they should be exited

If your sensor readings block permantently and you cannot prevent it. You could try to use `multiprocessing` to kill callback without the need of a flag to check...

```py
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions.states import add_state_features, Timeout
import time
import logging
import threading


@add_state_features(Timeout)
class CustomStateMachine(Machine):
    pass


class SimpleMachine(object):

    states = [{'name': 'dummy', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              {'name': 'start', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              'waiting']

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False  # our flag which will tell threads whether they should exit
        self.current_job = None  # where we save the running thread for joining
        self.machine = CustomStateMachine(model=self, states=SimpleMachine.states, initial='dummy')
        self.machine.add_transition('timeoutTransition', '*', 'waiting')

    def change_jobs(self, func):
        if self.current_job:
            self.running = False
            self.current_job.join()  # wait until job and thread exits
        self.running = True
        self.current_job = threading.Thread(target=func)
        self.current_job.daemon = False  # depends on your use case
        self.current_job.start()

    def on_enter_start(self):
        self.change_jobs(self.do_start_things)

    def do_start_things(self):
        print("doing 'things' for 15 secs, timeout should happen first")
        counter = 0
        start_time = time.time()
        while self.running and counter < 15:
            print("work work")
            time.sleep(1)
            counter += 1
        print("Spent %s seconds in start state" % (time.time() - start_time))

    def waiting(self):
        while self.running:
            print("wait for input")
            time.sleep(1)

    def on_enter_waiting(self):
        self.change_jobs(self.waiting)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    test_machine = SimpleMachine()
    print("State Machine started")
    test_machine.to_start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)  # make sure your main thread isnt exiting
```

### 2. Do work in 'internal' transitions (e.g. before callbacks) and trigger a 'heartbeat' events

What happens in heartbeat depends on the current state. In my opinion this will result in a cleaner experience than a having to rely on threads. Important: DO NOT BLOCK in callbacks but timeout for instance stale reading operations.

```py
from transitions import Machine
from transitions.extensions.states import add_state_features, Timeout
import time
import logging


@add_state_features(Timeout)
class CustomStateMachine(Machine):
    pass


class SimpleMachine(object):

    states = [{'name': 'dummy', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              {'name': 'start', 'timeout': 5, 'on_timeout': 'timeoutTransition'},
              'waiting']

    def __init__(self):
        self.running = False
        self.current_job = None
        self.machine = CustomStateMachine(model=self, states=SimpleMachine.states, initial='dummy')
        self.machine.add_transition('timeoutTransition', '*', 'waiting')
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger='tick', source='start', dest=None, before='start_tick')
        self.machine.add_transition(trigger='tick', source='waiting', dest=None, before='waiting_tick')

    def start_tick(self):
        print("work work")

    def waiting_tick(self):
        print("wait for input")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    test_machine = SimpleMachine()
    print("State Machine started")
    test_machine.to_start()
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
        test_machine.tick()
```

### Use `AsyncMachine` to cancel tasks when transitionting away from states

`asyncio.wait_for` will explicitely cancel a task when a timeout happens.
If you have a collection of tasks running in state, `AsyncMachine` will cancel them when changing states, even without asyncio timeouts. This requires `transitions > 0.8` and `Python > 3.7`. Note that `AsyncMachine` is a rather new addition to `transitions`.

```py
from transitions.extensions.asyncio import AsyncMachine
import asyncio
import logging


class SimpleMachine(object):

    states = ['dummy', 'start', 'waiting']

    def __init__(self):
        self.machine = AsyncMachine(model=self, states=SimpleMachine.states, initial='dummy')
        self.machine.add_transition('run', 'dummy', 'start')
        self.machine.add_transition('timeoutTransition', '*', 'waiting')

    async def doing_things(self):
        while True:
            print("work work")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

    async def on_enter_start(self):
        try:
            await asyncio.wait_for(self.doing_things(), 5)
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
            print("Timeout!")
            await self.timeoutTransition()

    async def on_enter_waiting(self):
        while True:
            print("wait for input")
            await asyncio.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
    test_machine = SimpleMachine()
    print("State Machine started")
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(test_machine.run())
```

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough explanation. Unfortunately other life stuff has got in the way and I haven't been able to circle back round to this to test any of the option scenarios you describe. I think I understand the forking of callbacks as you have explained it now so I realise why it is stopping prematurely.

I will mark this as the right answer for now (as I'm sure it is) and give you more feedback when I am able to try some of your suggestions. I think I will likely go down the AsyncIO route as I need to better understand Async IO for a new system we are developing at work.